# Unable to save results in results directory using jmeter with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

summary = 0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg: 0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err: 0 (0.00%) Tidying up ... @ Thu Nov 21 09:13:03 UTC 2019 (1574327583681) Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not read metadata ! ... end of run Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: what's JMeter version? did you tried with latest?

Answer (score 0):

As per your [Summariser](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode/) output:

> **summary = 0** in 00:00:0

it means that `0` [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) were executed, to wit your there are no results to parse/plot. I would recommend checking [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries, in case of JMeter failure the root cause can be figured out from the log file.

If you have problems with interpreting the log - update your question with the log file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transaction controller in your script?If that is the case then update following line to false in jmeter property file,it will resolve your issue[image]

**With value set to true** :[image]

**With value set to false:**
[image]